# Display datetime after selection

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

I'm using XDSoft datetime picker as inlined

```
<form id="dateForm" action="" method="post">

    <div id="test">
    {{ form }}
    </div>
    <script>
        $(function () 
        {
            $("#id_scheduled_time").datetimepicker
            ({
                format: 'd - m - Y H:i',
                inline:true,
                ...
            });
        });
    </script>
</form>
```

How can I display the picked datetime value beside the calendar ?

I've tried this:

```
var logic = function( currentDateTime )
    {
        div = document.getElementById( 'test' )
        div.insertAdjacentHTML( 'beforeend', currentDateTime );
    };
```

but nothing is displayed beside the calendar.

This is working but I don't want to use an alert:

```
var logic = function( currentDateTime )
    {
       alert( currentDateTime );
    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that you need to place a new element with the selected date as text content after the div with id test. If so, you can try the following

```
function logic(currentDateTime) {
  const test = document.querySelector("div#test");
  let span = test.nextElementSibling;

  if (span.nodeName === "SPAN" && span.textContent.trim() === currentDateTime)
    return;

  if (span.nodeName === "SPAN" && span.textContent.trim() !== currentDateTime) {
    span.textContent = currentDateTime;

    return;
  }

  const node = document.createElement("span");

  node.textContent = currentDateTime;

  test.parentNode.insertBefore(node, test.nextSibling);
}
```

Comment: Works ! but keeps appending currentDateTime to the HTML after each selection. Can I somehow refresh it so I can see only one each time I select a datetime ?

Comment: I read your comment until recently, in order to avoid creating extra span nodes, check if test node nextSibling is equal to `SPAN` if so return early. I have updated the answer

Comment: This will show the first selection only. I need to have the last one only ( these was what i meant about the concatenation ).

Answer (score 0):

To avoid appending datetime value to HTML each time I do a selection, I did this:

```
        var span= document.getElementById("Div1");
        if (typeof(span) != 'undefined' && span!= null)
        {
           span.textContent = currentDateTime;
        }
        else
        {
            span= document.createElement("div");
            span.setAttribute("id", "Div1");
            span.textContent = currentDateTime;
        }

        const test = document.querySelector("div#test");
        test.parentNode.insertBefore(span, test.nextSibling)
```